# pass Base Image value to Runtime image in docker file

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I am passing Stage=sandbox as docker Argument like below:

`docker build --build-arg STAGE=$Stage -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest .`

Now in docker I am getting Stage value in base image but not in runtime image:

```
ARG environment_default=sbx
FROM docker.image.net/dotnet:latest AS base
ARG STAGE
RUN echo $STAGE --> Getting Value here as sandbox

ENV environment_default=$STAGE
RUN echo $environment_default

#all other code

FROM docker.image.net/dotnet:latest AS runtime
ARG environment_default
RUN echo $environment_default --> NOT Getting Value(sandbox) here; instead getting default value(sbx)


ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=$environment_default
RUN echo $ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT

#all other code

ENTRYPOINT ['dotnet','exec','MY.Web.dll']
```

Comment: That matches the way I'd expect this to work: `environment_default` takes a `docker build --build-arg` value if present, or the specified default if not, and changing `ENV` in one build stage won't affect another.  Do you expect something different?  Do you need this "environment" value to be compiled into the image, or is it something you can specify at runtime?

Comment: Thanks for your comment David. Yes, I was expecting `STAGE` value to be set in `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` in my runtime image. I am not sure if I need to make  `ENV environment_default=$STAGE` or may be there is some other way to get STAGE value in runtime image.

Answer (score 0):

Changes made in one build stage won't affect another.  This includes the persisted image filesystem, metadata like the current user or container command, or environment variables.

There are only two exceptions to this:

1. You can explicitly `COPY --from` files from one build stage to another (but none of the other settings or metadata).
2. You can have a later stage built `FROM` an earlier stage and it will inherit *everything* from that stage.

In your case, you're setting an `ENV` variable in the `base` stage and expecting it to appear in the `runtime` stage; that simply doesn't happen, and there's no way to copy or propagate its value.  (As you've shown the Dockerfile, if you're using the current BuildKit backend, it probably won't run the `base` image at all since it's unused.)

You don't say what this environment variable is actually used for, or if its runtime value matters, but the easiest approach is to repeat the `ENV` statement in each stage that needs it, or just give the `ARG` the correct matching name.  Since you wouldn't typically rebuild your application or image for different environments, you also might be able to set this to a fixed value.

The only way you can really work around this is by dedicating a build stage to creating environment variables.  This will only work if your later stages happen to inherit from the same original image; in this case it does, but it's common to have a build stage with a larger tool set and a runtime image without a compiler or other (large) tools.

```bash
FROM docker.image.net/dotnet:latest AS environment
ARG STAGE
ENV environment_default=$STAGE

FROM environment AS base
RUN echo $environment_default

FROM environment AS runtime
RUN echo $environment_default
```

Comment: Thanks David. Yes, your solution worked but I am not sure if org allow me to inherit base image in runtime. Also, I tried putting `RUN echo $STAGE > /envfile.txt` in file in base image and tried to fetch it in runtime image and it worked using `RUN cat envfile.txt` but not sure how can I assign it to `ENV ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` ?

Comment: we are using sit image in prod instead of building new image in prod and our code must be identical in that case except configs which we can fetch it from ssm or secret manager.